# adding text to a only numeric text field for usability?

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK so i have this task that im not sure how to achieve. I have a text field that is only allowing the users to enter numeric values....I am validating on keypress to make sure that only numeric numbers are allowed

That works well

My problem is that the client wants text after the numbers to say " Miles" so if the user enters 100 they see "100 Miles"

I guess for usability. Does anyone know a good technique or jquery plugin to do this

Comment: why can't you put label saying "Miles" ???

Comment: that would be great...but its not my call....

Comment: That is, IMO, less usable. If at all possible you should explicitly tell the user what unit they are entering before they can start typing, or let them select from a list, or let them type it freeform and validate it upon submission. If at all possible, you should educate your client by providing him with alternatives and showing him pros and cons to each method.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to a javascript solution, you may also want to look into the HTML 5 `pattern` attribute for `<input>`. For example, in modern browsers you could do something like:

```
<input name="miles" pattern="^\d+\s?[Mm]iles$" required>
```

Which requires no javascript at all :) Here's the [relevant spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-pattern).

Comment: +1: this is cool. the prob is that we can only play around with this for now. its a lot of work to do an html5 site as of now as many of the major browsers wont support this.

Comment: @naveen Indeed, a javascript fallback is necessary. This is a good way to future-proof one's code though.

Comment: It's not all that helpful, you **must** validate on the server anyway, so don't tie yourself in knots doing things client side that are of little value.

Comment: @RobG The value is for the **client**; not having to waste time submitting a form, reloading a page, and re-entering information. This is valuable time spent performing the same task twice. Don't kid yourself, client-side validation is useful, I'd even go as far as saying a requirement.

Comment: @gf3—have you actually surveyed users? Client side validation should be as unobtrusive as possible, and never before the user has either left the field (blur) or submitted the form. The goal is to submit the form with valid values if possible, not to pester the user as they are trying to fill it in.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$('input').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
        // not a number
        return false;
    }
    // gets current entered numer
    var number = this.value.split(' ')[0];
    // adds new number
    number = '' + number + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    this.value = number + ' miles';
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier and I think clearer to do this in some sort of tag just outside of the textbox. Have a span directly below or something then update it on your keypress.

```
$('#textBox').keydown(function(){
    // Validation code
    $('#someSpan').html($(this).val() + " Miles");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that the client wants text after the numbers to say "
>   Miles" so if the user enters 100 they see "100 Miles"

Then you can handle it in the `onfocus` and `onblur` event of your `input type="text"` like this.

Try this

```
<input type="text" min="0" max="1000" step="1" id="distance" placeholder="Enter the value in miles"/>
```

And Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$("#distance").keypress(PassNumbersOnly);
    $("#distance").focus(OnFocus);
    $("#distance").blur(OnBlur);
});

function OnFocus() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().indexOf("Miles") != -1) {
        $this.val($this.val().split(" ")[0]);
    }
}

function OnBlur() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($.trim($this.val()) != "") {
        $this.val($this.val() + " Miles");
    }
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/EQEMr/

Answer (score 1):

How about this http://jsfiddle.net/TmxSN/1/

```
$(function(){

    var timerOutId;
    $('#inp').keypress(function(e) {
       var key = e.which;
        clearTimeout(timerOutId);
        try{
        if(this.value){
           this.value = $.trim(this.value.match(/\d+/g)[0]);
        }
        }catch(e){}    
        if ((key < 48 || key > 57) && !(key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 13 || key == 37 || key == 39 || key == 46) ){
           return false;
        }
    }).keyup(function(e) {
        var textBox = this;
        if(this.value){
          timerOutId = setTimeout(function(){
               textBox.value = $.trim(textBox.value.match(/\d+/g)[0]) + " Miles";
          }, 2000);
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: @Tamer - You can specify the delay as per your need before Miles text appear in the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Tell your client that anyone with enough intelligence to use the web can understand:

```
<label for="distance">Distance in miles:
 <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance"></label>
```

and that doing anything else is:

1. confusing for users
2. problematic as javascript may or may not be enabled/available
3. of zero practical use for the business as the value must be validated on the server anyway
4. the value requires additional processing at the server to remove the appended characters

Comment: _client_ that anyone _with enough intelligence_ : There is a direct conflict here. ;)